# How do I make the screen stretch the whole screen for react sandbox?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is my sanbox [project](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-forest-d50bvb?file=/src/styles.css)
Sorry I'm fairly new to react and don't know how to make the red color stretch to the whole screen for any type of device without specifying the pixels. You can see that there is white space in the sides present in the app https://d50bvb.csb.app/. I want the entire screen red.

I am trying to set width and height to 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
body
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

This will make the whole screen color to be red or whatever color you want to have.

Comment: It works! I didn't know that you could access an html element directly from the css even thought it isn't being loaded in the html. how is it working?

Comment: We can add CSS for specific tags like the body is tag so if anything added in the body tag the CSS will be applied globally.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-style-the-body-of-a-website-with-css


You can go through this for reference and more understanding and learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
body
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

This will make the whole screen color to be red or whatever color you want to have.